# HOW Android View compares to a composable

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

In the view World we can just use View.draw(canvas) to draw view on our Canvas (which might be connected to bitmap). But here in compose how can we achieve the same.

We have a draw modifier but it has no method draw(canvas)

**Update**

### What I need?

I wanted to blur a composable function by wrapping it inside a Blur Composable.
Suppose xyz() is any random composabel function.

```
 @Composable
fun xyz(){
// compose logic.
}
```

I want to create another fun called Blur().

```
@Composable
fun Blur(content: @Composable() -> Unit){
//Blur logic.
}
```

The Blur composable takes any composable function (say xyz()) as input and Blurs it.

### How I am going to implement it?

I thought I would take the same approach which the BlurView (A view blur library) takes.

- The Blur View is a frame layout.
- it blurs its content.
- The BlurView first creates the bitmap of the content; blurs it; then draws it.
- The function used to create teh bitmap of the content is `view.draw(canvas: Canvas)`

### Why I need this?

I thought of creating my version of BlurView in compose. I know in compose there is a Modifier.blur; but since this is only supported in api 31( I guess) so I can't use it in my project.

Answer (score 2):

In `Compose` there is a [Canvas](https://foso.github.io/Jetpack-Compose-Playground/foundation/canvas/) composable function available with `DrawScope`.
You can make use of that to draw.

DrawScope has `drawImage` function to take [ImageBitmap](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/graphics/ImageBitmap).
As you have Bitmap need to convert that using `Bitmap.asImageBitmap()`

Comment: I need view to draw on canvus not just random bitmap.

Comment: In [DrawScope](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/graphics/drawscope/DrawScope) you will have all Canvas operations.

Comment: That I Know and I am not looking for that. What I want is I want any random composable draw on my Canvas.

Comment: Can I describe more about the situation?

Comment: Thanks for ur time. Please re-read the question I have updated it.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this works or not.
In Blur composable function using interoperability.
AndroidView creates a view and inside, it takes a composable function.

Comment: Yeah I know that i can create Android View and then use the just like in view world but I was looking for a pure compose method. BTW, Thanks for your time much appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in another reply you can create a composable that uses a canvas and this will give you access to many of the same drawing methods you have in a regular View canvas.

```
@Composable
fun MyCanvasComposable(
    data: List<Int>, //some example data to pass in
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
        Canvas() {
            .. content here     
        }
}
```

Within the canvas you will be inside a DrawScope, which will allow you to do the canvas drawing as previous.

I'll add some examples assuming we're pulling the drawing logic into extension methods.

Examples:

Drawing some Text

```
internal fun DrawScope.drawSomeText() {
    //some logic here before drawing the text
    drawContext.canvas.nativeCanvas.drawText(
            [[your text]],
            positionX,
            positionY,
            paint
        )
}
```

Drawing a Path

```
internal fun DrawScope.plotXAxis(    
        //some custom rendering here followed by this method    
        drawPath(path, pathBrush, 0.5f)
}
```

In order to put your canvas on another layout you would call **MyCanvasComposable** with whatever layout modifiers are appropriate.

If you're trying to render other composables on top of the canvas the way you would do that is to just wrap the whole thing in a box and add the views before or after the canvas draw.

Example:

```
val myPainter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.src_image)
Box {

    Image(
        painter = myPainter
    )

    Canvas() {

        .. content here ..

    }

    Text( "some text")
}
```

In the above example you could also just call  **MyCanvasComposable** instead of **Canvas()**.

Note also **Image** will render before the canvas and **Text** will render after, which is to say on top of the canvas.

Comment: Thanks for you time. Much appreciated. I know I can get access to canvas using Canvus composable.

Comment: I will surely update the question once I am home?

Comment: I have updated the question. Please re-read it? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks again. I think you misunderstood my question. What I want to achieve is Blur any composable using my composable implementation.  Blur(@composable () -> Unit ) {// content to be blured}

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a `Bitmap` that has been blurred from your View function or methods like RenderScript mentioned [here](https://chiuki.github.io/android-shaders-filters/#/43), and draw landmarks or shapes on it you can use
`androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Canvas` instead of `androidx.compose.foundation.Canvas`

```
val option = BitmapFactory.Options()
option.apply {
    inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
    inMutable = true
}

val imageBitmap = RenderEffect.createBitmapEffect(Bitmap bitmap)
```

for api 31-

```
private Bitmap blur(Bitmap original, float radius) {
  Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
      original.getWidth(), original.getHeight(),
      Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

  RenderScript rs = RenderScript.create(this);

  Allocation allocIn = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, original);
  Allocation allocOut = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, bitmap);

  ScriptIntrinsicBlur blur = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(
      rs, Element.U8_4(rs));
  blur.setInput(allocIn);
  blur.setRadius(radius);
  blur.forEach(allocOut);

  allocOut.copyTo(bitmap);
  rs.destroy();
  return bitmap;
}
```

I'm not on my PC at the moment, when i'm available i will add it as modifier.

```
//  This is a function that returns Canvas which can be used to draw on an
// ImageBitmap that was sent as param. ImageBitmap that returned can be
// be used to display on Image or can be saved to a physical file.

val canvas: androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Canvas = Canvas(imageBitmap)

val paint = remember {
    Paint().apply {
        style = PaintingStyle.Stroke
        strokeWidth = 10f
        color = Color(0xff29B6F6)

    }
}

canvas.drawRect(0f, 0f, 200f, 200f, paint = paint)
canvas.drawCircle(
    Offset(
        imageBitmap.width / 2 - 75f,
        imageBitmap.height / 2 + 75f
    ), 150.0f, paint
)


// This bitmap has image and the drawing from canvas
Image(bitmap = imageBitmap, contentDescription = null)
```

Comment: Thankyou sir for ur help. What I first need is to draw composable on bitmap then blur it and emit new composable with result bitmap.

Comment: @SheikhZakirAhmad you need to use `RenderScript` as you can see how you can do it in the link i shared for below 31 api or `RenderEffect`, this is what Modifier.blur uses to blur an image, then you can use my answer after you get that Bitmap and draw on it and get the result ImageBitmap or Bitmap and set it to `Image`or save physical file

Comment: RenderEffect documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/RenderEffect)